# jQuery cannot reference dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I want to add a class to dynamically added content on success of `$(ajax)`.

I have the following function in an external Javascript file which is included at the beginning of the page. However, all code is executed within `document.ready()`.

The follwing function fetches items via AJAX and adds them to a list.

```
function GetCategories()
{
  var url = './ajax/training_management_data.php';
  $('#training_management_categories_items').html('<ul style="list-style: none; margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; padding:0px;" id="training_management_categories_items_ul"></ul>');
  $('#training_management_categories_items_ul').append(' \
    <li class="training_management_categories_list"> \
      <a href="" class="training_management_categories_list_a" id="training_management_categories_list_a_all">Alle</a> \
    </li> \
  ');
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      action: 'get_categories',
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
      var subid;
      var cssid;
      $.each(data, function(index, data) {
        subid = data.id;
        cssid = "training_management_categories_list_a_"+subid.toString();
        $('#training_management_categories_items_ul').append(' \
          <li class="training_management_categories_list"> \
            <a href="" class="training_management_categories_list_a" data-id="'+data.id+'" id="'+cssid+'">'+data.name+'</a> \
          </li> \
        ');     
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I have buttons to add, edit and delete items. All of these functions work fine. **However, after creating a new item I want to automatically "select" it (meaning I switch variables to the id of the selected item and apply the class `categories_selected` to it.** Selecting an item with clicking works:

```
$('#training_management_categories_items').on('click', '.training_management_categories_list_a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        categoryid = $(this).attr('id');
        selectedcategoryid = $(this).attr('data-id');
        selectedcategoryname = $(this).text();
        $("#training_management_categories_items>ul>li>a").removeClass('categories_selected');
        $(this).addClass('categories_selected');
    });
```

But if I call the function `selectEditedCategory`, it doesn't select the corresponding item. These are the two functions that are called when you click the "new"-button:

```
function startCategoryNewDialog() {
  $('#new_category_dialog').dialog({
    width: 250,
    height: "auto",
    show: {
      effect: "fade",
      duration: 300,
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "fade",
      duration: 300
    },
    draggable: false,
    open: function() {
      popupbg(true);
      $('#new_category_dialog_error').hide();
    },
    close: function() {
      popupbg(false);
    },
    buttons:{
      //Submit with click
      Anlegen:function(){
        submitNewCategory();
      },
      Abbrechen:function(){
        $('#new_category_dialog').dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });
}
function submitNewCategory() {
  var url = './ajax/training_management_data.php';
  if ($('#new_category_dialog_name').val().length < 2) {
    $('#new_category_dialog_error').html('<b>Fehler:</b><br>Der Name einer Kategorie muss mindestens 2 Zeichen lang sein.')
    $('#new_category_dialog_error').show( "blind" ,300);
  }
  else {
    $('#new_category_dialog_error').hide();
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        action: 'new_category',
        category_name: $('#new_category_dialog_name').val()
      },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function (data) {
        if (data[0].operation == 'success') {
          selectedcategoryid = data[0].id;
          GetCategories();
          selectEditedCategory(selectedcategoryid); //THIS IS THE CALL TO THE FUNCTION
          $('#new_category_dialog_name').val('');
          $('#new_category_dialog').dialog('close');
        }
        else if (data == 'error-name_present') {
          $('#new_category_dialog_error').html('<b>Fehler:</b><br>Kategorie mit gleichem Namen bereits vorhanden.')
          $('#new_category_dialog_error').show( "blind" ,300);
        }
        else {
          $('#new_category_dialog_error').html('<b>Fehler:</b><br>Fehler beim Anlegen der Kategorie.')
          $('#new_category_dialog_error').show( "blind" ,300);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

So now left is the function that doesn't work:

```
function selectEditedCategory(catid) {
  categoryid = 'training_management_categories_list_a_' + catid.toString();
  $("#training_management_categories_items>ul>li>a").removeClass('categories_selected');
  $('#'+categoryid).addClass('categories_selected');
  //$('#'+categoryid).trigger('click');
  //document.getElementById(categoryid).click();
  console.log(categoryid);
}
```

As you can see, I also tried referencing the id via getElementById and trigger.
However, Console returns no errors, categoryid is something like training_management_categories_list_a_80, where 80 is one ID fetched from the database.

If I view the Code with Firebug, it correctly shows me the links like this (just one example):

```
<div id="training_management_categories_items">
    <ul id="training_management_categories_items_ul" style="list-style: none; margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; padding:0px;">
        <li class="training_management_categories_list">
            <a id="training_management_categories_list_a_all" class="training_management_categories_list_a" href="">Alle</a>
        </li>
        <li class="training_management_categories_list">
            <a id="training_management_categories_list_a_85" class="training_management_categories_list_a" data-id="85" href="">Some Item</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is, it doesn't work. If I use `//document.getElementById(categoryid).click();` Console tells me getElementById is null but, as I said, if I view the source with Firebug the id is right and since I use jQuery append(), the elements should be properly inserted into DOM.

Any hints?

Edit: For better visualization, picture of the list:

[image: Picture of the Categories List]

Comment: Looks like a race condition to me. Are you sure that you are selecting the element *after* it has been added by the ajax handler? `selectEditedCategory` must run in a `.done` call.

Comment: For dynamically added items you must register the click event after you have created the element which is a pain. In such cases I prefer using an inline handler such as onclick="callFunction()".Most people are against the usage of inline event handlers. But for cases such as yours I prefer an inline handler

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff Yes, I am. The elements are inserted via `GetCategories()` and as you can see, the function `selectEditedCategory()` is called after that (inside `submitNewCategory()`.

Comment: @MDJ The problem is I don't want to use onclick. It works if I click it already, this is not the problem. What I'm trying to achieve is that the element gets "selected" after it is created, so this has to happen without click. Well in fact I wouldn't care to use trigger('click'), but that doesn't work since I cannot reference the element by its ID.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Got it.

Why not do this way.
Before calling the GetCategories function in submitNewCategory function.
Remove the styles of the all the selected categories.

```
              $("#training_management_categories_items>ul>li>a").
                removeClass('categories_selected');
```

Now in the place where you are creating your dynamic new category default the style of the dynamically created anchor tag to the class categories_selected like this

```
    <a class='categories_selected'>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't work like this. The item is created, and then `GetCategories()` is called, which fetches the items from the database and displays them. The ID of the category which was just created is only present in Javascript. So I can only select the item AFTER the list was reloaded. I have to do it that way because I have to make sure that the created item was properly stored in the database before you can use it.

Comment: Ok, Question : Once you create a new item,Are you loading the whole list again or just the new item created?

Comment: The whole list, because it gets sorted alphabetically. Added a picture of the list so you can get how it looks like. The category "Alle" is a "fake" category, all items are displayed in it, so it's not an item of the database (it has the id "training_management_categories_list_a_all")

Comment: Ok, pass the selected categoryid(the new item's id) to the GetCategories() function and in the $.each , add the class to the anchor. Something like this $.each(function(){if(id=newId){<a class='selected'/>}}); Hope this makes sense

Comment: Well GetCategories() is also called when the page first loads and after an item is deleted so I'll have to write a new function passing over that parameter. I get what you mean and I'm pretty sure it would work. However, I would really like to know why it doesn't work this way. It's not that this functionality is very important but I would really like to know what causes this. I hate using workarounds if I don't understand the source of the problem. No offence meant, I'm just trying to get a deeper understanding of the problem here.

Comment: Ok, The source of the issue is because the jquery.addClass you are using is equivalent to registering an event, meaning it will work for only already existing controls and not for those controls that are created dynamically in the future

Comment: This cannot be the source of the problem because the Item "Alle" is also created dynamically and can be referenced by a function (I didn't post that one here) which uses its ID. Also I use "append" when adding the items which means they are inserted as appendChild and registered to the DOM (and thus showing up in Firebugs source viewer).

Comment: You are right,The firebug source viewer shows the items after you code is run completely and the DOM is loaded. My point is that the elements are not loaded to the DOM when your code adds the class. Hence document.getElementById returns undefined. To verify you can try using a set time out function in your functions closure and add the class to using the id that you get from the DB which will work as the DOM is completely loaded.

Comment: Now we're talking! I didn't get your point first but you are right. Thanks alot.